# C2248 error with friend function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a basic overload of the << operator so I've added a friend function inside the class interface

```
namespace Warehouse
{
namespace Dto
{
    class Product;

    class AbstractOrder : public ICloneableItem
    {
      protected:
        unsigned long _id;
        std::string _name;
        std::vector<Product*> _products;

      public:
        AbstractOrder();
        virtual ~AbstractOrder();

        double computePrice() const;

        void addProduct(Product* product);
        void removeProduct(Product* product);
        void removeAllProducts();

        void setName(const std::string& name) { _name = name; }
        std::string getName() const { return _name; }

        unsigned long getId() const { return _id; }
        std::vector<Product*> getProductList() const { return _products; }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const AbstractOrder& ord);
    };
}
}
```

Inside the implementation file this is the code of the function

```
using namespace Warehouse::Dto;
....

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const AbstractOrder& ord) 
{
os << "[" << ord._id << "] Order " << ord._name << ": " << ord.computePrice();
return os;
}
```

Why I'm getting the following error?
Error   1   error C2248: 'Warehouse::Dto::AbstractOrder::_id' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'Warehouse::Dto::AbstractOrder'

Actually I've already fixed it,prepending the namespace before the operator<< on the implementation file. 
What I don't understand is why I have to do it even if in the implementation file I've used a **using namespace Warehouse::Dto** directive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol for friend function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430665/unresolved-external-symbol-for-friend-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ friend function can't access private members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731414/c-friend-function-cant-access-private-members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `operator <<` is defined in the global namespace and the `AbstractOrder` class is defined in the `Warehouse::Dto` namespace. But the friend declaration is for a stream operator in the `Warehouse::Dto` namespace.

If you want to defined proper friend declaration for the operator in the global namespace is would be:

```
friend std::ostream& ::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const AbstractOrder& ord);
```

But then again you want the operator to live in the same namespace as the class it is streaming.